# Migration Path from RPG.SE

Tags: discussion, migration

[Tool Recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tool-recommendation) Questions on RPG.SE recently [became off-topic](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5747/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic-revisited) there.

I had many useful interactions with that tag over there and would like to see them here.

The most important thing that we would need to know is that we would have to edit context into the question when it comes over so its clear the question is about role playing games. Because obviously, that context is not included in the questions there :)

I [asked a question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5842/3324) on their meta about the same topic.